# Buildfire: phone notch detection

Tags: buildfire

Is there a way to detect if the device running my plugin has a front camera notch in the screen such as the Iphone X?

I would like to be able to add space at the top of the screen if a notch is detected and leave the space out if not?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following css environmental variables:

`padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top)`

`padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-bottom)`

https://medium.com/@draganeror/iphone-x-layout-features-with-css-environment-variables-d57423433dec